# How to get background image property in fabric js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

I can't find any official documents. I may not have found it, but please let me know if you know.

I want to get the top and left values of the background image.

If that value doesn't exist, it's okay if it's the coordinates of the current background image.

Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can find background position with lineCoords object

```
 canvas.backgroundImage.lineCoords
```